# An example of a nilpotent group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, nilpotence

Is there an example of a nilpotent group such that $G/G'$ is (non-trivial) torsion-free while $G$ is not? I cannot think of any example of this kind and I think that it is not proved any result like this, am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group ?

Comment: Yes but how to make it partially torsion-free? What type of ring one has to choose?

Comment: As Myself (implicitly) says, if you consider $H = \langle x,y : [x,y,x] = [x,y,y] = 1 \rangle$, and then consider $ \tilde{H}/\langle [x,y]^{2} \rangle,$ you will see that $\tilde{H}$ is nilpotent, has torsion, but has Abelianization $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh! That is nice!

Comment: @GeoffRobinson What is $\;\overline H\;$ in your comment?

Comment: Is the factor group of $H$ with the subgroup generated by $[x,\, y]^2$. One could also take $H$ to be directly the group with presentation $\langle x,\, y\, :\, [x,y,x]=[x,y,y,]=[x,y]^2=1\rangle$ I think.

Comment: Yes, you could. @Timbuc: , I made a typo, it should have been $\tilde{H} = H/\langle [x,y]^{2} \rangle.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson You think too highly of me :-) (Actually I  overlooked that $G$ must have torsion.)

Comment: @Myself : In general, it's probably best to think too highly of people unless and until you have reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, all relatively free groups of rank $k \geq 2$ in the variety defined by the law $[a_1, ... a_n]([x, y])^m$ for some fixed integers $n$ and $m$ satisfy this condition. Such groups are indeed nilpotent of degree $n$, all their commutators have finite orders dividing $m$ and their abelianization is the free abelian group of rank $k$.